# How to combine select_related() and value()?

Tags: django

We know there is a `values()` method of `QuerySet`, when there is a foreign key (author, for example), it result like:

```
[{ 'author_id':3, ... }, ...]
```

I want a result like:

```
[{ 'author':{'name':'dave',...}, ... }, ...]
```

and I tried `select_related`, but `values()` won't show the detail of the foreign key, what can I do?

Comment: For newer django versions (1.7+) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595085/how-to-combine-select-related-and-value-2016/35598358#35598358

Comment: @Risadinha the link you posted also works with Django 1.3.7 for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Django doesn't have builtin support for that. `select_related` never changes the outcome of a queryset, only the number of queries when you access related object.

You could use [DjangoFullSerializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) to get something that is similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the **unicode** method of each Model, and print it.

```
class Book(..):
    title = models.CharField(..)
    color = models.CharField(...)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s" %(title, color, author)

class Author(...):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name
```

Comment: reading your question again, I think I've totally missed the mark.