# Django select_related does not work

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My django select_related works very weirdly

```
Models:
class Publisher(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 class Meta:
      app_label = 'models'
      db_table = 'Publisher'
class Book(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 publisher = models.OneToOneField(Publisher)
 class Meta:
      app_label = 'models'
     db_table = 'Book'
```

Output:

```
books = Book.objects.select_related('publisher').all()
print books.query
SELECT "Book"."id", "Book"."name", "Book"."publisher_id", "Publisher"."id", "Publisher"."name" FROM "Book" INNER JOIN "Publisher" ON ( "Book"."publisher_id" = "Publisher"."id" )
print books.values()
[{'publisher_id': 1, u'id': 1, 'name': u'rest framework'}]
```

Django generates the correct query and data is retrieved when I execute it. But values do not contain Publisher

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211349/how-to-combine-select-related-and-value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're slightly misunderstanding how `selected_related` works. Referring to the [django docs on `select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

> **`select_related`** returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
> selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
> **This is a performance booster** which results in a single more complex
> query but means **later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
> database queries.**

As you already determined, adding `select_related` causes django to select the related-object's data (`Publisher.id` & `Publisher.name` in this case). However, the `all()` method will still only return a `Book` QuerySet.

Where this is useful is when you access a `Book`'s `Publisher`, django will not need to query the database again for the `Publisher`:

```
# Hits the database.
# SELECT "Book"."id", "Book"."name", "Book"."publisher_id" ...
b = Book.objects.get(name='Twilight')

# Hits the database again to get the related Book object.
# SELECT "Publisher"."id", "Publisher"."name" ...
p = b.publisher
```

That's two database queries, whereas the `select_related` lookup is only one:

```
# Hits the database, but already includes Publisher data in the query
# SELECT "Book"."id", "Book"."name", "Book"."publisher_id", "Publisher"."id", "Publisher"."name" ...
b = Book.objects.select_related('publisher').get(name='Twilight')

# Doesn't hit the database, because b.publisher has been prepopulated
# in the previous query.
p = b.publisher
```

(example is a slight variation on the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) example)

Comment: Why do you use 'Entry' in your example?