# How to combine select_related() and value()? (2016)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.7

I am asking this question again ([it was asked back in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211349/how-to-combine-select-related-and-value)),

> We know there is a `values()` method of QuerySet, when there is a
>   foreignkey  (author, for example), it result like:
>
> ```
> [{ 'author_id':3, ... }, ...]
> ```
>
> I want a result like:
>
> ```
> [{ 'author':{'name':'dave',...}, ... }, ...]
> ```

Has something changed in the newer versions of Django?

I want to convert the query set into a combination of lists and dictionnaries, is it possible?

I will then take this object and place it into a bigger object to serialize it. It is the reason why I don't want to serialize it right away.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can access related fields via [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) without the necessity to use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) (only these will be fetched without subsequent lookup):

```
MyModel.objects.values('author__id', 'author__name')
```

This will return the following structure:

```
[{'author__id': 1, 'author__name': 'Dave'}, {...}]
```

If you need it in a nested structure you would have to transform it afterwards.

Note that for M2M relations, this returns one list entry per M2M relation, so probably not a desired effect. But for OneToOne/ForeignKey relations it works just fine.

EDIT: for M2M relations [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) in combination with `values()` works fine.

Comment: The issue, however, is that this creates an outer join. AFAIK you need to use select_related to create an inner join, so the question remains.