# How can I convert Inner Join and Group By to Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to change this raw SQL to Django ORM but I couldn't manage to convert.

```
most_read_students = LendedBook.objects.raw('
SELECT student_id as id, name, surname, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM "Book_lendedbook" 
INNER JOIN User_student on Book_lendedbook.student_id=User_student.id 
where did_read=1 
group by student_id 
order by count DESC 
LIMIT 5')`
```

I tried this and I get close result.But unfortunately, I couldn't do what I want. Because I want to join this table with another table.

```
most_read_students = LendedBook.objects.values('student_id')
.filter(did_read=True, return_date__month=(datetime.datetime.now().month))
.annotate(count=Count('student_id'))
```

When I use select_related with "User_student" table like this;

```
most_read_students = LendedBook.objects.select_related('User_student')
.values('student_id', 'name', 'surname')
.filter(did_read=True, return_date__month=(datetime.datetime.now().month))
.annotate(count=Count('student_id'))
```

It throws an error like `Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: book, book_id, did_read, id, is_returned, lend_date, return_date, student, student_id`

But I should be able to get student properties like name and surname when I join "User_student" table.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!
[How to combine select_related() and value()? (2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595085/how-to-combine-select-related-and-value-2016)

Funny fact; my problem was not about ORM i guess. I didn't know I could reach student object's properties by just adding this to `.values('student__name', 'student__surname')` in the last code I've shared on this post.

This code ;

```
 LendedBook.objects.select_related('User_student')
.values('student_id', 'name', 'surname')
.filter(did_read=True, return_date__month=(datetime.datetime.now().month))
.annotate(count=Count('student_id'))
```

To this code ;

```
LendedBook.objects.select_related('User_student')
.values('student_id', 'student__name', 'student__surname')
.filter(did_read=True, return_date__month=(datetime.datetime.now().month))
.annotate(count=Count('student_id'))
```

By the way, deleting `.select_related('User_student')` doesn't affect the result.

**So, using _ _ solved my problem!**